# Laravel blade multiple select. How to select records in the pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel, multi-select

I am using Laravel, and I have a projects table and a users table. Each project can have multiple users. I have set up a project_user pivot table.

I am trying to create a multiselect box that lists all users, and has the users currently assigned to the project selected. Here is my ProjectsController function that creates the view.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $project = Project::findOrFail($id);
    $users = User::lists('name','id');
    return View::make('projects.edit', compact('project','users'));
}
```

And here is the relevant blade form:

```
{{ Form::select('user_id[]', $users, ??? , array('multiple')) }}
```

Where I think ??? should be an array of user_ids associated with the project. Can I get that from

```
$project->user...something here?
```

Or, do I need to create the array in function edit()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. First make sure you have the correct relationship defined in your project model

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('User');
}
```

Now to get the ids of all assigned users:

```
$assignedUserIds = $project->users()->lists('id');
```

And just pass that to the view...

Comment: I replaced `???` with `$project->users()->lists('user_id')` and it's working. Thank you!

Comment: Sure you can do it in the view directly as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer is right except on Laravel 5.2 I had to do **->toArray()**:

```
$assignedUserIds = $project->users()->lists('id')->toArray();
```

to get this to work with Form::select.

I would have commented original answer, but I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$assignedUserIds = $project->users()->lists('id');

to
// I used in laravel 5.7
$assignedUserIds = $project->users()->pluck('id');
```